# Series movie similar to "The Twilight Zone"

Tags: story-identification, movie

20+ years ago I watched on TV several SF series movies. I remember about one episode quite clearly, and until recently I was sure that it was "The Twilight Zone". However, I watched the entire series of "The Twilight Zone", and that episode never appeared.

Episode description

A child (boy) is afraid to be bullied (again) by children at the playground. The father decides to support his child, and help building his self-trust, as well as deal with the bullies. The father was himself a victim of bullying when he was a child. They go together to the playground. They decide to use the playground slide. While they slide down, the child repeats saying loud "I'm the father, I'm the daddy, I'm the pa..." At the end of the slide, the father became a child, and the child an adult. The bullies arrive, the child (adult size) gets scared and runs away, and the father (now child size) remains to re-live the horror of being bullied, like in his real childhood.

So, the questions:

1. What movie was the one I just described?
2. What other movies are very similar in "design" to "the Twilight Zone"?

I tried searching on the net for this, but nothing showed up - nothing relevant, I mean.

Comment: I don't recognise the episode so won't put it as an answer, but try The Outer Limits.

Comment: @Jontia: Tanks for the hint. I will look into that series also, even if it is not related to the episode described.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"The Playground"
An episode of The Ray Bradbury Theatre (1985)
Starring William Shatner as the devoted dad.

A caring father, deeply traumatized by the constant bullying he suffered as a child at the local playground, is forced by his sister to face his demons and take his little boy to the same playground. However, the demons return as well.

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0683228/

Comment: Wow! This one was a quickie :) Thanks. I verified on youtube (for less than 10 seconds) and it looks like that this is the one. Thank you.

Comment: Another note: Obviously, I haven't seen the original Star Trek series at that time, I would have recognized William Shatner - like I did now ;)